# How to display single post details on Magento home page using fishpig wordpress integration extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, fishpig

I have install fishpig WordPress integration in my Magento website, I want to display single post details on my Magento's Homepage using static block ( with post ID ).
so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom .phtml file in your template and call this

```
<?php
$data=Mage::getModel('wordpress/post')->getCollection()->setOrderByPostDate()->addIsPublishedFilter()->addPostTypeFilter(array('post'))->setPageSize(1);
?>
<div id="learn">
<ul class="xyzs" id="carousel1">
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($data as $post){
{
?>
<li class="item">
<?php if ($featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage()){ ?>
<div class="custom-image"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $featuredImage->getAvailableImage(); ?>"/></div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="learn_pragrap">
<span class="custom-date"><?php echo $post->getPostDate(); ?></span>
<h2><?php echo $post->getPostTitle(); ?></h2>
<p> <?php echo substr($post->getPostExcerpt(),0,149); ?> </p>
<div class="buttons-set">
<a class="button posts" title="Learn More" href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>"><span><span>View Full Story</span></a>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php //} $i++;

} ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

After this, you can call your .phtml file in cms home page. After that call static block on your home page using this command:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom/custom.phtml"}}
```

Comment: It is Working fine :)
Thank you @Abhinav Kumar Singh